# Windows Not Honoring DHCP Scope

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, dhcp

Please bear with me as I'm not a networking person by trade.

Our current configuration at work includes two Windows Servers serving as DHCP/Active Directory servers (if that makes sense) -- one replicating from the other.  On both machines, the DNS resolution is set up as:

[image: DNS Server List]

That is:

1. Internal Windows Box
2. External Provider
3. External Prover
4. Internal Windows Box

Assuming our domain is foo.com, we maintain the foo.com website on a hosted VPS with it's own IP address.

The problem is that even though bar.foo.com is an internal server and is defined in DNS on the Primary Windows machine, when I ping **bar** or even **bar.foo.com** it resolves to the hosted IP address instead of the 10.* address.

I tried taking both of the Public IP addresses out of the DHCP scope, and that seemed to work, but it completely slowed down access to any external sites, so that wasn't acceptable.  I also tried adding the two Windows machine as the DNS servers on my desktop.  That too worked, but I'd rather not have everything enter their DNS servers, as the above setup should theoretically be working.

Is there anything I could check to see why pinging **bar.foo.com** isn't resolving to the DNS entry on the Windows machines?

Here's a summary of the ping results, if they help:

---

Pinging from servers with static IP

**bar.foo.com** resolves with **correct** IP address

---

Pinging from linux machines not joined to the domain

**bar.foo.com** resolves with **correct** IP address

---

Pinging from user's desktop machines, joined to the domain, but dynamic IP

**bar.foo.com** resolves with **incorrect** IP address

---

This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Honestly, I can't figure out what you're trying to achieve or how you've got things configured. Why do you have the Verizon ip addresses in a DHCP pool? Why do you have your servers acquiring their ip addresses via DHCP instead of having them statically assigned?

Comment: Servers are getting their IP addresses statically assigned.  The user's machines are getting them from DHCP.  Interesting, from the servers, pinging **bar.foo.com** does resolve correctly -- it's from the user's machines that things get strange.

Comment: So is your problem with DNS or DHCP?

Comment: DNS, sorry, I updated the question.  According to someone that was helping me, the problem was that DHCP scope looked like it wasn't getting properly applied, so that's what lead me down that line of verbiage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DHCP server should be handing out the IP addresses of your DCs as the DNS servers. Your DNS servers should have an entry for bar.foo.com that points to the internal IP address. After you do this, renew your IP address and everything should work.

Comment: That's the problem.  The internal DNS servers **do** have an entry for bar.foo.com.  For some reason it's skipping the DCs though and going right out to the public DNS servers.

Comment: When I do `nslookup` on bar.foo.com, I get the right (internal) IP.  When I `ping` bar.foo.com, I get the wrong (external) IP.

Comment: @jerhinesmith, flush DNS in between tries with `ipconfig /flushdns`?

Comment: @jerhinesmith - You should NEVER configure external DNS servers when you have active directory setup. Only use AD DNS servers. Don't even put the public DNS servers in there as a backup.

Comment: @chris-s Tried that.  /release and /renew as well, just for funsies.  No dice.  It's really aggravating that it resolves on Linux but not Windows.

Comment: @jerhinesmith - Also, check your DNS server bindings. They could be listening on an address that doesn't exist or isn't accessible from the clients. Then they wouldn't be responding to requests which would explain why they're being skipped.

Comment: @jason-berg: How do sites resolve to the outside world then?  Is that through the router entry?  Also, last time I tried removing them, non-internal DNS lookups were excruciatingly slow (I assume because it had to fail over from both AD machines).

Comment: @jason-berg, where would I look for the DNS server bindings?

Comment: Sites resolve to the outside world through forwarders or root hints. If you go into the properties of your DNS servers, you can setup forwarders there. Anything that doesn't hit on the internal DNS records would be forwarded on. The other option is root hints. That's a slower process for small shops. So configure your forwarders!

Comment: @jerhinesmith - within DNS manager, right click on the name of the server and go down to properties. The interface tab is where you configure binding. The forwarders tab is where you configure forwarders.

Comment: @jason-berg - Holy crap, you might be right.  There's 4 ip addresses in the fowarders section that are from a long, long time ago when we were in a different office.  If this works and our paths ever cross, there's a beer or beverage of your choice with your name on it.

Comment: @jerhinesmith - Stone Smoked Porter - Yummy :-)